# Would it be helpful it I posted a Q/A to server management

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a general tendency here for new server admins to want to install a desktop on his or her server and then forward part or more often the entire desktop over ssh or VNC server.

I am of the opinion web interfaces are a better choice as outlined in my answer here:

[Remote GUI, Windows client, Ubuntu 16.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967281/remote-gui-windows-client-ubuntu-16-04-server)

I am willing to write a question from a new user perspective asking about graphical tools for server management and post the answer I already wrote there.

I would post it as a community wiki.

The goal would be to have a community resource for server management.

Would such a Q/A topic be useful ?

EDIT: Started here - [Graphical Server Management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967704/graphical-server-management/967710#967710)

Answer is community wiki so please feel fee to review / edit / comment / update.